# Unable to use django-kronos

Tags: python, django, django-kronos

I've been testing django-kronos with the simple example listed in the github readme:

I did `pip3 install django-kronos`,

myproject/myapp/cron.py:

```
import kronos
import random

@kronos.register('* * * * *')
def complain():
    complaints = [
        "I forgot to migrate our applications's cron jobs to our new server! Darn!",
        "I'm out of complaints! Damnit!"
    ]

    print random.choice(complaints)
```

In my myproject/myproject/settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'appointments.apps.AppointmentsConfig',
    'clinic.apps.ClinicConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_extensions',
    'bootstrap4',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'parsley',
    'session_security',
    'kronos'
]
```

Ran:

```
./manage.py runserver
```

I expected the dev server to throw up a message every minute. Nothing seems to be happening.

I also created myproject/myapp/management/commands/task.py:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
import kronos
@kronos.register('* * * * *')
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        print('Hello, world! KRONOS is running!!')
```

This is also not running.

Comment: What does `crontab -l` output. Is there anything in your /var/log/cron*log file? Is `crond` alive?

Comment: @RedCricket It says there are no crontab for me. In /var/log, there are no files starting with cron

Comment: Well you should have cron log file somewhere. What OS are you using?

Comment: @RedCricket Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Comment: @RedCricket I've checked /var/log/syslog with a grep for CRON, and all I get are cron by the OS: `Nov 22 23:39:01 hp CRON[28037]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Nov 22 23:45:01 hp CRON[28502]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Nov 22 23:55:01 hp CRON[28900]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Nov 22 23:59:01 hp CRON[29087]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 60 2)
`

Comment: I am sure Ubuntu has a log file for cron somewhere. I was reading the Django-kronos docs and it says your need to register your jobs with cron like so: `$ python manage.py installtasks`